# Angular app stops receive an exception after publish

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, exception

Here is a basic Asp net core application with angular 8, created from a visual studio's 2019 template.

Could someone explain
why when I receive an error from API and throw an exception at client's backend during debug session via Visual studio, method in component.ts receive that exception successfully.

But, after publish the app (publish to folder via VS2019, then copy files to IIS and convert to app)
, there is just a 500 error, but according log file my exception was throw.

component.ts has a method

```
createRelatedTask() {
    if (this.validation()) {
      this.taskService.createRelatedTask(this.relatedTask).subscribe(
        result => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        },
        error => {
          this.showMessage(error.error, error.message);
        });
    }
  }
```

taskService.ts has a method

```
createRelatedTask(relatedTask: RelatedTaskData) {
    return this.http.post<RelatedTaskData>(this._baseUrl + 'TaskService/', relatedTask);
  }
```

TaskServiceController

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<RelatedTaskInfo> CreateRelatedTask(RelatedTaskInfo relatedTask)
{
     var result = await _taskService.CreateRelatedTaskAsync(relatedTask);
     return result;
}
```

TaskService

```
    public async Task<RelatedTaskInfo> CreateRelatedTaskAsync(RelatedTaskInfo relatedTask)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var apiClient = new RelatedTaskClient(httpClient) { BaseUrl = _relatedTaskApiSettings.ApiAddress };

            var dto = Map(relatedTask);

            try
            {
                var response = await apiClient.CreateRelatedTaskAsync(dto);

                var result = Map(response);

                return result;
            }
            catch (ApiException e)
            {
                var text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(e.Response);
                throw new Exception(text);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
```

[while running via VisualStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OofRJ.png)

[when published to IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcsAu.png)

Comment: a little update: there is an empty response from TaskServiceController to taskService.ts request when the app hosted in IIS

Comment: Well, this article helped me a little 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#exception-handler-page
At least now I can pass error message to a client form.
Added to startup.cs lambda for UseExceptionHandler.